# How to update only several rows basing on returning?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table with orders:

```
uid | status
```

And items:

```
uid | order_uid | status
```

I need to update order's status if all of its items has their certain statuses. To process whole table I would do:

```
UPDATE orders o SET status=2
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items i WHERE o.uid = i.order_uid AND status != 2)
```

But in my case I need to perform this on several orders which are returned as a column from the previous items update:

```
with order_uids(order_uid) as (
    update items ...
    returning order_uid
-- Update orders here
```

How can I do this without `FOREACH` loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `RETURNING` clause and `IN` comes to mind:

```
with order_uids (order_uid) as (
      update items ...
      returning order_uid
     )
UPDATE orders o
    SET status = 2
WHERE o.order_uid IN (SELECT ou.order_uid FROM order_uids ou) AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM items i WHERE o.uid = i.order_uid AND status <> 2)
```